# Prove that $A \subseteq B \iff P(A) \subseteq P(B) $ where $P(X)$ is the power set of $X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Prove that $A \subseteq B \iff P(A) \subseteq P(B) $

(1) $$P(A) \subseteq P(B) \implies A \subseteq B$$
$$A \in P(A) \Rightarrow A \in P(B)$$
By definition of the power set, we have that $A \subseteq B$ 
(2) $$A \subseteq B \Rightarrow P(A) \subseteq P(B)$$ 
$$\forall x(x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B)$$
$$\{x \}\in P(A) \Rightarrow \{x \} \in P(B)$$
$$P(A) \subseteq P(B)$$ 
Is my proof correct?

Comment: The first half is very nice. How about $X\in P(A) \implies X \subseteq A \implies X \subseteq B\implies X \in P(B)$

Comment: A word of advice: Proofs should have words gluing the various parts together, and they shouldn't just be sequences of equations concatenated together. I recommend going back and trying to embed these into a short paragraph.

Comment: @stevengregory 
What about the second half?

Comment: For the second part, you have to show that ***every*** subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$, which is very easy to do, but showing that every one-element subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$ is not the way to do it.

Comment: $(X\in P(A) \implies X \subseteq A \implies X \subseteq B\implies X \in P(B)) \implies (P(A) \subseteq P(B))$

Comment: I cannot follow it.

Answer (score 0):

$$A \subseteq B \iff P(A) \subseteq P(B)$$

$(\implies)$

Assume $A \subseteq B$. Then $S\in P(A)$ implies $S \subseteq A$ implies $S \subseteq B$ implies $S \in P(B)$. Hence $P(A) \subseteq P(B)$.

$(\Longleftarrow)$

Assume $P(A) \subseteq P(B)$. Then $x \in A$ implies $\{x\} \in P(A)$ implies $\{x\} \in P(B)$ implies $\{x\} \subseteq B$ implies $x \in B$. Hence $A \subseteq B$.